# What class actually does the formatting of a composite format spec?

Tags: .net

If I specifiy a FormatString property for some databound value of {0:00000}, where I want a number to always have five digits, padded with '0' where necessary, what method on what class is actually invoked to perform the formatting and return the formatted string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the formatted object itself, its class has to implement [IFormattable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx)

```
public interface IFormattable
{
    string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider);
}
```

And so any type, like `struct Int32` can do its own formatting. In absence of the interface `Format()` defaults to the normal `ToString()`.

Comment: Aha, pity class String does not implement that interface.  I would have liked to experiment with some numeric formats on strings that are numeric.